# Issue in query while using OrderBy in Google Sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I was trying to include a sort in the query function in google sheet. Without the order by the formula works and gives me the result. Once the sort is added, it only gives me the first row

Initial Formula

```
=QUERY('Car Info'!A:E,"select C,D,E,B,A where D < date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and ((E >= date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') or E is Null)",1)
```

With Order by

```
=QUERY('Car Info'!A:E,"select C,D,E,B,A where D < date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and ((E >= date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') or E is Null)" order by A Asc,1)
```

What is the mistake I am making? Could someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to go inside the enclosing `"`, try:

```
=QUERY('Car Info'!A:E,"select C,D,E,B,A where D < date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and ((E >= date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') or E is Null) order by A Asc",1)
```